# Submitting a list of names in C# form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a C# form with controls like this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="pos1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="pos2" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="pos3" runat="server" />
...
```

After submission I process them like this:

```
List<int> pos = new List<int>();
pos.Add(Int32.Parse(pos1.Text));
pos.Add(Int32.Parse(pos2.Text));
pos.Add(Int32.Parse(pos3.Text));
...
```

Is there a way to directly store the posted values as a List without manually adding the value of each text field. To clarify, in PHP I can do this:

```
<input type="text" name="pos[]" />
<input type="text" name="pos[]" />
<input type="text" name="pos[]" />
...
```

Which is then available to me like this:

```
$_POST[pos[0]];
$_POST[pos[1]];
$_POST[pos[2]];
...
```

I.e keeping the name of inputs as pos[] for all inputs they are automatically available as `$_POST[pos[n]]` is there a way to achieve a similar effect in ASP.NET

Comment: so not being able to  create **name** value is your issue ..correct ??

Comment: The name is automatically created in C# but in C# I cannot use it as an array. I have to use pos1 pos2 pos3 I'd like to use the same id and on the server get the values as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FindControl` to do something similar, but not *exactly* the same.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)FindControl("pos" + i);
}
```